# How to add bars on upper and lower X-Axis in Tikz BoxPlot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles, boxplot

I need to show green bars on the x-axis of a tikz boxplot as shown in the following figure. (The green bars indicate whether the corresponding question to this value is positive when the value is high or low.)

[image]

I have drawn boxplot similar to this using the following Latex code. But I couldn't draw the green bars on the x-axis (top and bottom).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
boxplot/draw direction=y,
ylabel={Scores},
ytick={1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5},
yticklabels={1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5},
ymin = 0.8, ymax = 5.3,
width=\textwidth,
boxplot={
    box extend=0.3,
},
xtick={0.5,...,20},
x tick label as interval,
xticklabels={
{Q1},{Q2},{Q3},{Q4},{Q5},{Q6},{Q7},{Q8},{Q9},{Q10}
},
    x tick label style={
        text width=1.5cm,
        align = center
    },
    xmin=0,xmax=11
]
\addplot[draw=black,fill={rgb:red,4;green,2;yellow,1}]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {data\\5\\4\\5\\5\\4\\4\\3\\5\\};

\addplot[draw=black,fill={rgb:red,2;green,1;yellow,2}]
 table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {data\\1\\2\\1\\1\\1\\2\\2\\1\\};

\addplot[draw=black,fill=green!50!red]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {data\\4\\5\\5\\5\\5\\4\\4\\5\\};

\addplot[draw=black, fill=black!50]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {data\\1\\1\\1\\2\\1\\2\\2\\3\\};

\addplot[draw=black, fill=blue!50!red]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {data\\5\\4\\5\\5\\4\\5\\4\\5\\};

\addplot[draw=black, fill=green!50!blue]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {data\\1\\1\\2\\1\\1\\2\\2\\3\\};

\addplot[draw=black, fill=red!50!yellow]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {data\\5\\4\\4\\5\\5\\4\\3\\4\\};

\addplot[draw=black, fill=black!20]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {data\\2\\1\\1\\1\\1\\2\\1\\2\\};

\addplot[draw=black, fill={rgb:red,1;green,2;blue,3}]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {data\\4\\4\\5\\5\\5\\4\\4\\5\\};

\addplot[draw=black, fill={rgb:red,0;green,0.5;blue,1}]
 table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {data\\2\\1\\2\\2\\1\\2\\2\\2\\};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{SUS Usability}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The corresponding figure:

[image]

How can I create those green bars as in the first image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! You could just add them in a loop.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
boxplot/draw direction=y,
ylabel={Scores},
ytick={1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5},
yticklabels={1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5},
ymin = 0.8, ymax = 5.3,
width=\textwidth,
boxplot={
    box extend=0.3,
},
xtick={0.5,...,20},
x tick label as interval,
xticklabels={
{Q1},{Q2},{Q3},{Q4},{Q5},{Q6},{Q7},{Q8},{Q9},{Q10}
},
    x tick label style={
        text width=1.5cm,
        align = center
    },
    xmin=0,xmax=11
]
\addplot[draw=black,fill={rgb:red,4;green,2;yellow,1}]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {data\\5\\4\\5\\5\\4\\4\\3\\5\\};

\addplot[draw=black,fill={rgb:red,2;green,1;yellow,2}]
 table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {data\\1\\2\\1\\1\\1\\2\\2\\1\\};

\addplot[draw=black,fill=green!50!red]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {data\\4\\5\\5\\5\\5\\4\\4\\5\\};

\addplot[draw=black, fill=black!50]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {data\\1\\1\\1\\2\\1\\2\\2\\3\\};

\addplot[draw=black, fill=blue!50!red]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {data\\5\\4\\5\\5\\4\\5\\4\\5\\};

\addplot[draw=black, fill=green!50!blue]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {data\\1\\1\\2\\1\\1\\2\\2\\3\\};

\addplot[draw=black, fill=red!50!yellow]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {data\\5\\4\\4\\5\\5\\4\\3\\4\\};

\addplot[draw=black, fill=black!20]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {data\\2\\1\\1\\1\\1\\2\\1\\2\\};

\addplot[draw=black, fill={rgb:red,1;green,2;blue,3}]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {data\\4\\4\\5\\5\\5\\4\\4\\5\\};

\addplot[draw=black, fill={rgb:red,0;green,0.5;blue,1}]
 table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {data\\2\\1\\2\\2\\1\\2\\2\\2\\};
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,10}{%
\path ([xshift=-1ex]axis cs:#1,1) coordinate (aux-#1);
\ifodd#1
\fill[green!60!black] (aux-#1|-current axis.north) rectangle ++(2ex,-0.75ex);
\else
\fill[green!60!black] (aux-#1|-current axis.south) rectangle ++(2ex,0.75ex);
\fi}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{SUS Usability}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks.